# Save() is not updating data in table in datamapper with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datamapper

Hi I am new to codeigniter i have written code to update one table data goes in right manner but it's not updating in database table and it's fire insert query instead of update .

here is my controller method Clients is table

```
public function editClients($id="")
        {
            Auth::RequireFleetindia();
            $this->template->set("fleet_india");
            $this->template->setData("SelectedTab", "Clients");

            $this->Clientsedit = new Clients();
            $this->Clientsedit->where(array("account_id"=> Auth::get("id"),'ID'=>$id))->get();

            if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
            {   echo $this->Clientsedit->ID;
                $this->load->library('form_validation');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('clientname', 'Client Name', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'required');
                $is_unique='';
                if($this->input->post('clientemail') != $this->Clientsedit->email) 
                {
                       $is_unique =  '|is_unique[clients.email]';

                } 
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('clientemail', 'Client Email', 'required|valid_email'.$is_unique);

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('daily_rate', 'Daily Rate', 'numeric');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('daily_contract_mileage', 'Daily Contract Mileage', 'numeric');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('excess_mileage_rate', 'Excess Mileage Rate', 'numeric');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('daily_contract_time', 'Daily Contract Time', 'numeric');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('overtime_rate', 'Overtime_Rate', 'numeric');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('night_shift_rate', 'Night Shift Rate', 'numeric');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('overtime_incentives', 'Overtime Incentives', 'numeric');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('taxrate1', 'Tax Rate', 'numeric');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('taxrate2', 'Tax Rate', 'numeric');



                if($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE)
                {
                    $this->Clientsedit->client_name             =   $this->input->post('clientname');
                    $this->Clientsedit->address                 =   $this->input->post('address');
                    $this->Clientsedit->email                   =   $this->input->post('clientemail');
                    $this->Clientsedit->daily_rate              =   $this->input->post('daily_rate');
                    $this->Clientsedit->daily_contract_mileage  =   $this->input->post('daily_contract_mileage');
                    $this->Clientsedit->excess_mileage_rate     =   $this->input->post('excess_mileage_rate');
                    $this->Clientsedit->daily_contract_time     =   $this->input->post('daily_contract_time');
                    $this->Clientsedit->overtime_rate           =   $this->input->post('overtime_rate');
                    $this->Clientsedit->night_shift_rate        =   $this->input->post('night_shift_rate');
                    $this->Clientsedit->overtime_incentives     =   $this->input->post('overtime_incentives');
                    $this->Clientsedit->taxrate1                =   $this->input->post('taxrate1');
                    $this->Clientsedit->taxrate2                =   $this->input->post('taxrate2');


                    if($this->Clientsedit->save())
                    {
                        echo '<pre>';
                        print_r($this->Clientsedit);
                        echo '</pre>';
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Client Updated');
                        //redirect("fleet_india_client/editClients","refresh");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $error = $this->Clientsedit->error->string;
                        echo $error;
                        echo $this->Clientsedit->address ;
                        //redirect("fleet_india_client/editClients","refresh");
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    //$this->load->view("fleet_india/clients/editClients");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view("fleet_india/clients/editClients");
            }
        }
```

Comment: In order to see why it's inserting new rows instead of updating, I think you need to post the `$this->Clientsedit->save()` method. My guess is that is where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for commenting not there is no problem with save method it is of datamapper and working fine in other controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake there was problem with my table in database. i have not set primary key to id , that's why it's not updating need to set primary key for the field by which you want to update any record in table using data mapper.

Thanks to everyone for commenting.